# Xamarin forms: How to make tabs on bottom of the page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am looking for tabs which will be on the bottom part of the page. I tried the [xamarin forms TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page), but for **ios** only the tabs are coming bottom and for **android and windows** the tabs are showing on the top. Is there any way to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Edit**: for new Xamarin.Forms projects you should use [Xamarin.Forms Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/), it provides easy tabs and other great features.

To accomplish that you have 3 options:

**1)** To use new bottom tabbar native control you must have Xamarin Forms version 3.1 or above.

On your tabbed page you need to add the android specification for bottom placemente:

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    x:Class="YouProjectNameSpace.MyTabbedPage">
</TabbedPage>
```

**Or c# code behind**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YouProjectNameSpace
{
    public partial class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MyTabbedPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want more customization you can add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    BarBackgroundColor="#2196F3"
    BarTextColor="White"
    android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#66FFFFFF"
    android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="White"
    x:Class="YouProjectNameSpace.MyTabbedPage">
</TabbedPage>
```

**2)** Create a custom renderer for Android of the tabbed page and move it to the bottom

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YouProjectNameSpace
{
    public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
    }
}
```

And the renderer:

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace YouProjectNameSpace.Android
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context): base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            this.InvertLayoutThroughScale();

            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }

        private void InvertLayoutThroughScale()
        {
            this.ViewGroup.ScaleY = -1;

            TabLayout tabLayout = null;
            ViewPager viewPager = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; ++i)
            {
                Android.Views.View view = GetChildAt(i);
                if (view is TabLayout tabs)
                    tabLayout = tabs;
                else if (view is ViewPager pager)
                    viewPager = pager;
            }

            tabLayout.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(new GlobalLayoutListener(viewPager, tabLayout));

            tabLayout.ScaleY = viewPager.ScaleY = -1;
        }

        private class GlobalLayoutListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener
        {
            private readonly ViewPager viewPager;
            private readonly TabLayout tabLayout;

            public GlobalLayoutListener(ViewPager viewPager, TabLayout tabLayout)
            {
                this.viewPager = viewPager;
                this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
            }

            public void OnGlobalLayout()
            {
                this.viewPager.SetPadding(0, -this.tabLayout.MeasuredHeight, 0, 0);
                this.tabLayout.ViewTreeObserver.RemoveOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3)** Use specific library like [PXTabs](https://github.com/c-lamont/PXTabs), this one creates a full Xamarin Forms bottom tabs without any native code.

If you want to read more about bottom tabs and renderers:

[Setting TabbedPage Toolbar Placement and Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/tabbedpage-toolbar-placement-color)

[Xamarin.Forms: Official Bottom Navigation/Bottom Tabs on Android](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-official-bottom-navigation-bottom-tabs-on-android/)

[BottomNavigationBarXF](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: And for windows?

Answer (score 2):

c# code worked it.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YouProjectNameSpace
{
    public partial class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MyTabbedPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is also for windows?

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you.